# Is there a way to generate variables from pymc3?

Tags: python, pymc3

If I have a model like the one below, how do I access the theano function in order to get the value(s) for my model I'm fitting?

This is quite a basic model and so I could just calculate with the raw `function` for my variables. However, I intend to generate pymc3 models dynamically where some variables are reused/fixed/bounded etc.

I know I can access the theano function from `model.makefn([expected])` but this will rely on transformed arguments like `sigma_log_` instead of `sigma`.

Ideally, I'm looking for something like `model.evalute([expected], alpha=1, beta=2)`

Is there such a method?

Thanks

```
def function(a, b):
   # do something

basic_model = Model()

with basic_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=10)
    beta = Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=10, shape=2)
    sigma = HalfNormal('sigma', sd=1)

    # Expected value of outcome
    expected = Deterministic('expected', function(alpha,beta))
    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = Normal('Y_obs', mu=function, sd=sigma, observed=Y)
```

Answer (score 2):

The typical approach here would be to first sample from the model's posterior distribution with something like

```
with model:
    trace = pm.sample(N_SAMPLES)
```

then use the samples to approximate the posterior expected value of your function.